# Order Missing in dashboard but present in database

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

It seems that an order is missing in the woocommerce order tab, however in the database the order is present. How can I push this to woocommerce order tab so that it is available there?

Order ID is present in wp_posts and wp_postmeta. I'm not sure what caused this but would like to know why so we can prevent it from happening again.

Answer (score 0):

This often happens because the order status is not defined for WooCommerce. You may have a plugin that has added new order status and is currently disabled. Check the status of the order inside the `wp_posts` table in the `post_status` field. The default WooCommerce statuses are listed below:

- Pending payment – wc-pending
- Failed – wc-failed
- Processing – wc-processing
- Completed – wc-completed
- On-Hold – wc-on-hold
- Cancelled – wc-cancelled
- Refunded – wc-refunded

You can change the status of the order manually to be displayed in the order list at the Wordpress admin panel.